# How to get songs from internal and external storage?

Tags: java, android, uri, mediastore

I'm using MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI to get songs from external storage, and for internal i should use MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.

But how can i use both so that my device scans for songs on internal and external storage?

```
Uri musicUri = ((location == "internal") ?
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI:
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    Uri genreUri = ((location == "internal") ?
            MediaStore.Audio.Genres.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI:
            MediaStore.Audio.Genres.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    Uri playlistUri = ((location == "internal") ?
            MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI:
            MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

I tried something like this, but how can i implement location as both internal and external?

Comment: Mediastore holds all your media located in internal and external sdcard. All you need is private final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

Comment: And equivalents for media and genres